# The median of a continuous frequency distribution

Tags: statistics

[image]

For number b :

The order of the median is $13$ , then it lies in the first class $0-1$

Now i do not know what is the lower bound of this class ?

Is it $-0.5$ ?

Comment: The lower bound you use for interpolation should perhaps match the upper bound, so use $-0.5$ and $1.5$ or use $0$ and $1$ to take into account that you can only have an integer number of accidents.  Either way, you also need to consider whether your estimate of the median should be an integer in a discrete distribution.

Comment: In this case what the accumulative frequency for $-0.5$ would be ? Is it zero ?@Henry

Comment: In answer to your question the cumulative frequency here below the lower bound is indeed zero.   I am guessing this (*lifts* rather than *elevators*) may be for something like English A-level S1, in which case you need to follow what the syllabus requires, and I do not know what that is, though I would expect the estimated median to be $1$ as an integer.

Comment: It is indeed A-level S1 but the answer in the book is 0.722 so i got confused @Henry

Comment: $0.722 \approx \frac{13}{18}$ so it seems that to get that answer you would need to use $0$ and $1$ as the bounds and interpolate between them.  Not what I would do without that prompt

Comment: Thank you @Henry