# Find the median by interpolation

Tags: statistics

[image]

The order of the median is $13$ , then it lies in the first class $0-1$

Now i do not know what is the lower bound of this class ?

Is it $-0.5$ ?

Comment: You are supposed to convert the class limits to continuous class boundaries like $[-0.5,1.5],[1.5-3.5],[3.5-5.5]$. This way you have common class widths. So yes, lower bound can be taken to be $-0.5$.

Comment: Please do not repost: [The median of a continuous frequency distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3557016/the-median-of-a-continuous-frequency-distribution)